# Html.Action и AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

У меня есть метод (без метки '[HttpPost]' => GET?)

```
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
       public async Task<ActionResult> UserFriendsPartial(int userId, int count)
       {
            var friends = await RelationshipService.GetFriendsByUserId(userId, count);
            return PartialView(friends);
       }
    }
```

Есть представление

```
<div id="UserFriends">
    @Html.Action("UserFriendsPartial", "Home", new { userId = Model.Id, count = 6 })
</div>

<button id="AddToFriends"/>

<script type="text/javascript">

 $('#AddToFriends').click(function () {
            FriendsRefresh(6);
        });

 function FriendsRefresh (pCount) {

            var p = {
                userId: @Model.Id,
                count:  pCount
            };

            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("UserFriendsPartial", "Home")',
                type: 'POST',
                contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
                data: JSON.stringify(p),
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#UserFriends').html(data);
                }
            });
        }

</script>
```

При загрузке страницы метод вызывается через Html.Action (если методу добавить в контроллере метку HttpPost, то работать не будет).
А при нажатии кнопки этот же метод вызывается AJAX POST запросом.
Вопрос - почему это работает?

Comment: может здесь userId: @Model.Id кавычки нужны userId: '@Model.Id'

Comment: @akrasnov87 в том то и дело, что всё работает отлично, я просто не могу понять как метод контроллера без метки HttpPost может вызываться AJAX POST запросом и как(GET или POST) его вызывает Html.Action

Answer (score 2, accepted):

у вас есть метод, обрабатывающий оба типа запросов `GET` и `POST`. Когда вы вызываете метод контроллера через Html.Action, то суть запроса (его глобальные заголовки) не меняется. Он у вас как был (вероятно) `GET` так и остается таким же. То есть при вызове метода, глобальный запрос  все тот же, и для вызова Html.Action новый запрос (Request) не формируется.

Когда вы к методу добавляете атрибут `[HttpPost]` вы ограничиваете обрабатываемые методом контроллера http-методы запроса только одним - `POST`. Поэтому при вызове Html.Action для глобального `GET` это более не работает, а для `POST`-запроса через `Ajax` работает.